# How to get multiple images from a single Drupal node using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom content type in Drupal that allows multiple image uploads through a single field.  I want to programmatically access the image URI's, apply my theme, and then get the output one by one. I can do this with a single image like so,

```
<?php
$image_style_name = 'my_theme';
$image_uri  = $entity->field_image['und'][0]['uri'];
$image = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $image_style_name, 'path' => $image_uri));

$image = image_style_url($image_style_name, $image_uri); ?>
```

but I am unsure how to access the entire array of images.

**For anyone who needs it... the full solution:**

```
<?php
$image_style_name = 'my_theme';

foreach($entity->field_image['und'] as $key => $value){
$image_uri  = $entity->field_image['und'][$key]['uri'];
$image = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $image_style_name, 'path' => $image_uri));
$output = image_style_url($image_style_name, $image_uri);    
echo $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in the `$entity->field_image['und']` array so you should be able to loop over the array and theme each one with something like

```
foreach($entity->field_image['und'] as $image_field){
  ..etc
}
```